# Problem with MySQL VALUES using PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to send data from an AJAX call to database tables that are generated from PHP. I'm wrapping the MySQL queries in a function with for loops so I can create any number of tables on the fly. I have every part of it working except for the query that defines the VAULES. I'm trying to append an integer variable at the end of $usrscore so that as it loops through, my VALUES will be $usrscore1, $usrscore2, $usrscore3, etc. The problem is that it only picks up the integer as the value (i.e. 1, 2, 3) instead of using the entire variable (i.e. $usrscore1, $usrscore2, $usrscore3).

Concatenating doesn't work (i.e. "$usrscore" . $counter . ") and combining them as two separate variables doesn't work either (i.e. $usrscore + $counter). If I literally write out the variable with an integer at the end it works as expected but I need this to work in a loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code, and the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i guess you want to call a variable, but don't know it's name.
you must concatenate them like:

```
$myvar1 = 'hi there';
$str = 'myvar';
$int = 1;
echo ${$str.$int};
```

it must return

```
hi there
```

hope it helps